# Programatically install Dokan with my C# app?

Tags: c#, installation, dokan

I have an app that requires [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en).
When the app starts, I wish to check whether Dokan is installed or not.
If it's not, how do I install it?
I have the installer file, but how do I silently install it? I don't want to bother the users with yet another GUI.

Comment: Normally, there are some commands for installers and you can call the setup.exe file with some parameters like /s or something that let you install the app silently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, there are some commands for installers and you can call `setup.exe` file with some parameters like `/S` or something that let you install the app silently.
Capital S is specific for NSIS installers.

Answer (score -1):

Just put the dll files and exe file in your application directory and they will be used by your application when necessary.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I just throw the Dokan files in my app directory? But how about the driver? And the mounter service??